# How is "++argv" correct in this program from "The C programming Language by Dennis Ritchie"?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, command-line, program-entry-point

The main function has second parameter as **char * argv[]** , that is an array of pointers.In the same book it has been mentioned that we can't use operations like "++" on array names. But, here we can see ++argv has been used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char* line, int max);


/* find: print lines that match pattern from 1st arg */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    long lineno = 0;
    int c, except = 0, number = 0, found = 0;

    while (--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-')
    {
        while (c = *++argv[0])
        {
            switch (c) 
            {
                case 'x': {
                    except = 1;
                }
                    break;

                case 'n': {
                    number = 1;
                }
                    break;

                default: {
                    printf("find: illegal option %c\n", c);
                    argc = 0;
                    found = -1;
                }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (argc != 1)
    {
        printf("Usage: find -x -n pattern\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0) 
        {
            lineno++;

            if ((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except) 
            {
                if (number)
                {
                    printf("%ld:", lineno);
                }

                printf("%s", line);
                found++;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Please indent properly.

Comment: What if I was to say: pleaseindentthecode, not as easy to read as if I put spaces on it, right?

Comment: Function parameters that look like arrays are really pointers.  You can increment pointers; you can’t increment array names that are not function parameters. Which edition of K&R are you using?  Both are a bit old, but you should not be using the first (1978) edition.

Comment: hello, Sorry for the not so well presented code, however its not the logic of the code or working of the code I am referring to, my question is simply that, how can we use increment on an array name?

Comment: Hello, I have formatter your code for you. Any code posted, should be legible.

Comment: Not that it's poorly written, but why learn C from a book originally written 40+ years ago and last updated 30+ years ago?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the clarification , I am using second edition. In the same text I have read a segment where it has been mentioned that, if we use array names as parameters in function defination , we wouldn't be able to carry out such operations on the array name....!

Comment: @FiddlingBits I am actually preparing for an competitive exam, and this was the most recommended book for C in regards to the exam, so had to take it up..

Comment: I’m away from my copies of K&R (I have both, but I got K&R 1st when it was the only edition), so I won’t be able cross-check for a few days.  However, I suspect you’ve misinterpreted what it says.  Maybe with page numbers, people can check.

Comment: @Brandon  thanks for the help. This was my first question here, will be more careful from here on.

Comment: @Narender Makes sense.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler its on page 83 , section 5.3.

Comment: Can you check the reference, @Narender?  My K&R1 has Section 4.9 (Initialization) on p83, and my K&R2 has sections 4.6 Static Variables and 4.7 Register variables on p83.  It is a first printing of the second edition, but a wholly different chapter seems unlikely for a revised printing. —— In my K&R2, section 5.3 is on p97ff.  On p99, it says: _There is one difference between an array name and a pointer that must be kept in mind. A pointer is a variable, so `pa=a` and `pa++` are legal. But an array name is not a variable; constructions like `a=pa` and `a++` are illegal._ . Is that your quote?

Comment: If I identified the correct material, the next paragraph says: _When an array name is passed to a function, what is passed is the location of the initial element. Within the called function, this argument is a local variable, and so an array name parameter is a pointer, that is a variable containing an address._ . And `argv` is, of course, a function parameter…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array as a parameter to a function is automatically converted to a pointer.  So this:

```
char *argv[]
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
char **argv
```

That's why you're allowed to do `argv++`.